# Excel scanning using powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I want to scan the second column of an excel file and if the value is "zero", it should display the first column value in the same row.How to write a powershell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$File = "$pwd\test.xlsx"

#Setup Excel, open $File and set the the first worksheet
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file)
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$SearchString = "Some Value"

$Range = $Worksheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn
$Search = $Range.find($SearchString)

$Search.value() = "Another Value"
```

The line:

```
$Range = $Worksheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn
```

sets a range for the entire A column. If you prefer, you can specify a fixed range like so:

```
$Range = $Worksheet.Range("A1","A5")
```

We then set the output from the find method to the $Search variable in this line:

```
$Search = $Range.find($SearchString)
```

We simply pass the search string, in this case $SearchString, as a parameter in the find method on a NamedRange object. Note that the returned value will be $null if the search does not find a match.

And, finally, we change the value of the found cell:

```
$Search.value() = "Another Value"
```

There are also FindNext and Find Previous methods that can be called if you want to find all instances.

**Source**: **[Here](http://daniellange.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/searching-excel-in-powershell/)** - Further Reading [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/02846fc2-4808-413d-9ab6-d05b709ee29a/powershell-searching-of-excel-document) & [Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9c3b233b-1690-4aa6-80bf-9379bc4e60e3/powershell-and-search-in-excel-file-get-a-row-values)

Comment: I got some idea from your post. But actually I need to display the value of all the rows in column A:A where the search result is zero in all the rows in the column B:B.